# How to call multiple methods using loop in Java?

Tags: java, methods, call

Supposes I have some methods like this:

```
method1()
method2()
method3()
method4()
method5()
```

But I don't want to call sequence methods:

```
obj.method1()
obj.method2()
obj.method3()
obj.method4()
obj.method5()
```

It's boring. And if I add a new method: `method6()`, I need add manual: `obj.method6()`

It's better if I can call them using a loop in Java. Anybody can give me some suggestions?

Thank!

.

Comment: Before you do this, consider whether the methods could be better named, and whether it would be simplest just to write one method that calls them all.

Comment: Would it not be better to add a method to your `obj` to call the method sequence? (I assume those are the real method names.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
   for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
      try {
        obj.getClass().getMethod("method"+i).invoke(obj);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         // give up
         break;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void callABunchOfMethods(Object obj, int count) throws Exception {
  for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    obj.getClass().getMethod("method"+i).invoke(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why you have used such naming convetion for your methods. If it was not only for example, you should consider to find better solution for them. Today it could be obvious for you but for followers of your code not really.

Regarding the manual addition of hypothetical `method6`. I think that adding one line of code is betther than reducing it and lossing the clarity of the code.

My suggestion is that, you should use the [Facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)